# Как найти все имена в которых есть буквы 'a' и 'd'?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как найти все имена в которых есть буквы 'a' и  'd'?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: эм. `name like '%a%' or name like '%d%'`? Или через `InStr(name, 'a') >0 OR InStr(name, 'd') >0`?

Comment: нет, попробовал но не правильно

select first_name from employees where first_name like '%a%' and first_name like '%d%'

Comment: сейчас второе попробую

Comment: @Vladko Так ты ищешь имена, в которых есть И та, И другая буква. Если надо ИЛИ - то вместо `and` надо использовать `or`. Кроме того, в зависимости от текущего COLLATION сравнение может выполняться с учётом регистра или без.

Comment: Akina, да, я понимаю, вверху использовал 'and'
select first_name from employees where first_name like '%a%' and first_name like '%d%'

Comment: и не сработало?? Да как так-то. Может у вас в запросе или в бд буквы `а` отличаются? К примеру в БД на английском, а вы пишите на русском или наоборот

Comment: нет, все сделал, спасибо. неправильный  символ написал один

Answer (score 0):

```
select first_name
from employees
where first_name like '%a%' and first_name like '%d%';
```